# How to add external dependencies on HDInsight Jupyter?

Tags: azure, jupyter, azure-hdinsight

I am using HDInsight Spark clusters on Azure, and Jupyter fails to add external dependencies. Tried this:

[image]

However, if I make an intentional mistake:

```
%%configure
{ "packages":["com.websudos:phantom_2.10:1.27.111111111111"] }
```

So this is trying to resolve packages, just not loading them?

[image]
Is there any other way to make this thing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are using is not the right one. The intentional mistake is actually telling you that it cannot resolve that package.

It seems the package you might actually want to use is `com.websudos:phantom-spark` since that's what they built Spark support on? [Link](https://github.com/nosheenzaza/phantom-data-centric)

```
%%configure -f
{ "packages":["com.websudos:phantom-spark_2.10:1.8.0"] }
```

and then you can import

```
import com.websudos.phantom.spark._
```

However, if what you want is a Spark-Cassandra connector, the [datastax connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) seems to be the one to use.

I should say I've never used Spark with Cassandra before, so please do follow tutorials online on how to set them up.

Comment: That is what I've come to understand as well, phantom does not support code distribution in spark, and only those packages are not working on jupyter (works if I spark-submit them). Phantom-spark is not open source AFAIK. And yes, spark-cassandra-connector is helpful with storing dataframes, but I wanted to use cassandra's counters for some custom stuff, anyway, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the spark-submit command you are executing that does work and the code that proves it works?

Comment: Sorry, cant. Moved to AWS.